# Ring and field theory

Tags: field-theory

Is $R/ker(\phi)$ and field if $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism from R to R' where both are commutative and rings with unity?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Not necessarily. If $R$ is commutative with unity,  $R/\ker\phi$ is a field if and only if $\ker\phi$ is a maximal ideal.

Comment: I left out the fact that the $ker(\phi)$ is also properly contained in $N$, where N is a proper ideal as well. I did this so that I would be able to make the conclusion myself that is not a field, thanks to Arturo Magidin given the condition you mentioned. Thank you!!!